# Alternative to returning malloc'd data in c?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

In C, I have this function here:

```c
// Returns human friendly byte amount
char *byteconvert(unsigned long b_) {
    float b = (float) b_;
    int n = 0;
    while (b / 1000 >= 1) {
        b /= 1000;
        n++;
    }
    char *buffer = malloc(32);
    sprintf(buffer, "%.2f%c", b, "BKMGT"[n]);
    return buffer;
}
```

Do I just assign a variable to this function call and then free it later? What if I want to just print it, something like this:

```
int x = 123456;
printf("Size: %s\n", byteconvert(x));
```

How can I do this without memory leak? This seems like a basic question in C, and I just don't know the correct way to go about this.
I found many posts similar to this online, but none of them had a definite or good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this without memory leak?

you need to free the memory after use.

```
int x = 123456;
char * temp = NULL;

temp = byteconvert(x);
printf("Size: %s\n", temp);

//after use just free it
free(temp);
```

Comment: Also, how about in a loop? Can I use the same variable or do I need to free it every time?

Comment: need to free it every time. Because every time you will call it. it will malloc new memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on the caller doing `free` then have the caller pass in the buffer in the first place.

Also you should check `n < 5` before using it as array index.

```
void byteconvert(unsigned long b_, char *buf, size_t buf_len )
{
    ...
    snprintf(buf, buf_len, "%.2f%c", .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. Store the pointer returned by `byteconvert()` in a variable, and free it when it is no longer needed.